# What must I do to legally create a MMO browser game?

Tags: internet

I am an adult programmer who knows (absolutely) nothing about law.

## What must I do to start a MMO browser game?

I mean a massively-multiplayer online browser game similar to (for example) Travian, OGame or Tribal Wars.

1. Assume I will do all the work alone *(hiring people to help me could be a follow-up question for another occasion)*.
2. If it matters, assume the game will be in english.
3. Assume the game URL will be the straightforward **www.(something-here).com** *(assume I already own this domain - even though I don't - this could be a follow-up question if I can't figure it out by myself)*
4. Assume all players will play together (i.e. there won't be separate servers for different countries).
5. Assume players can send messages to each other within the game.
6. Assume the game will be 100% free to play.
7. Assume the game won't have any advertisement (I would pay all the expenses myself).

*(These assumptions are supposed to narrow down my question - on another occasion I may worry about these details)*

When I ask "what must I do?", I am asking regarding law, of course. What laws must I follow? Must I do something special considering I am "just another citizen"? Do I have to create a company first? In short, again, **what must I do?**

---

I will be happy to give any other details that you might need.

**If this depends on the country I live in, answer based on your favourite country - at this moment I just want to have an idea of how it works. Country details can be left for another time.** Unless I am very lucky and you know the specific laws for Brazil.

Remember I don't know anything about law - I probably don't even know how to hire a lawyer.

Comment: This question is clearly too broad - you are asking us what is involved in establishing a business *and* IP law *and* internet law *and* contract law. You really need to do some preliminary research and come back with specific questions on things you don't understand.

Comment: @DaleM thanks. Sorry about that - I will continue my search and narrow down my questions further, hopefully asking separate questions later. Thanks.