# How to make sure my website complies with things like COPPA?

Tags: internet

I want to start an online browser game following all laws.

A few days ago I heard of [COPPA - Children's Online Privacy Protection Act](http://www.coppa.org/). In this link, they clearly explain in all details what must be done, and what kind of website must comply. As a person that knows (absolutely) nothing about law, I am glad to find this right-to-the-point text that tells me exactly what to do.

My question is, **how do I find out if there are other things like this to follow?** I am glad I heard of COPPA, otherwise I would have no idea I had to follow it. I am now worried that **there might be other laws to follow that I don't even know they exist.**

**How to make sure I am following everything that must be followed?** Is there some kind of "list"? **I am using COPPA just as an example - I don't want to be restricted only to privacy laws. The thing is, I can't even dream of what other laws could exist.** (I'm lucky to have found COPPA)

I am brazillian, the website would be hosted in Brazil. But I would like people from other countries to be allowed to play as well. *(I don't know if this matters)*

*If you really need to know more details about the game to properly answer this question, let me know and I will add them - but I was hoping to a more general answer first, so I can analyse them  myself and decide what is needed and what is not. I am not sure if this question is too-broad the way it is now - if it is, I will add the details.*

---

**EDIT:** I don't think this question is a duplicate from [Where can I find a comprehensive document of computer laws?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/where-can-i-find-a-comprehensive-document-of-computer-laws). Even though its title suggests that, both answers only refer to security and hacking. I am talking about the content of my website, and I am not "hacking" anyone nor doing anthing close to that.

**EDIT 2:** Just to clarify, I do not expect someone to show up with a complete list and solve my problem like magic. The thing is, as of now I have not the slightest idea of how to proceed.

I mean, (at least the majority of) existing MMO browser games (like Clash of Clans, Neopets, Club Penguin, OGame and such) must have done *something* to make sure they comply with all needed laws.

Comment: Ban anyone 13 of younger from using your site (via your TOS).

Comment: @Andy thanks, but it seems I am not allowed to do that if my website is considered to be "directed to children". Also this question is not directed to COPPA, but asks about other laws that could exist that I am not aware of.

Comment: @Andy also, please take a look at [this other question I asked](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/how-to-block-children-under-13-to-access-my-website-and-still-comply-with-coppa).

Comment: One more comment, which is that games like Clash of Clans, etc, almost certainly hired an IP lawyer to draft user agreements, and do a comprehensive regulatory analysis. Just so you know the type of undertaking this is, if you intend to do it yourself or if you intend to hire out the project: this is not boilerplate work and the regs are not going to be easy for most non-lawyers to wade thru. Secondly, if I were hired to do this project, I would need a minimum of a 5k retainer and a clear understanding that the end product would take a while and cost in excess of that #...maybe by double. FYI

Answer (score 5):

The FTC has myriad regulations (depending on site/content/ etc.) that must be complied with - this is especially true if children will be interacting with others. Ideally, you should have the assistance of an intellectual property attorney or a regulatory specialist if this is something you expect to be wide reaching and/or geared toward children.

All of that being said, the following link offers much information regarding compliance with COPPA for small entities. If you plan on doing the compliance work yourself, there is also a liaison, or virtual "help desk" run by the FTC. Depending on what you're doing and your ability to interpret complex regulatory frameworks, you could accomplish this yourself.

I'd recommend that you start here, where you'll find links to other regulations that may be applicable and easily found, and then decide if you need a specialist based on the breadth of your work product and what you find that may apply. Or, at a minimum, you may be able to narrow the scope of your question after reviewing this help section, if you find you need help analyzing a certain section.

https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I studied the link you gave me and I believe I understand COPPA now. But I think your answer only partially addresses the question: you gave me more details on COPPA and suggested I could find links for other regulations. This does not really fully answers my question, because I want to know **how to make sure I follow everything**, not what can I do to possibly find other laws. You said "Ideally, look for an IP attorney", and I am aware it might be the only answer, but I will hope for other answers that could give me more guidance. If none shows up, I'll accept yours! :)

Comment: That's sort of why I suggested you may want to narrow your question a bit. Some of the language you use in your question is so all encompassing, I find it difficult to address what it is exactly you are looking for. To ensure you comply with every regulation, statutory scheme, local/state/federal guideline would be impossible without (a) knowing exactly what you are doing, how/who it is being marketed, and myriad other facts; and (b) would be far more information than would be possible to post as an answer to a site like this that is supposed to be more generalized information. If you narrow..

Comment: I may be able to expound further or give you more resources to ensure compliance without the help of a professional. This is generally a big undertaking.

Comment: you're very welcomed by the way!

Comment: Thank you very much for the goodwill and wholeheartedness! I really appreciate it. Now I would like to politely ask your patience - you helped me realize that I have to thoroughly think what exactly my doubts are, and how to divide/separate them, to save everyone's time and attract better answers. Once I'm ready, I will either edit this question or ask a new one (and let you know, if you don't mind).

Comment: In the meantime, you might be interested in looking at my ["root question"](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1893) - my final goal is to get a fulfilling answer for it. Also, [this other question](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2034) is quite similar to what I want to know, except that I want (much) more details. Again, I will rethink everything, and see what are the correct questions I have to ask, and how to make them suitable for this site. You might see me asking other sub-questions around :) Thanks again.

Comment: One more comment, which is that games like Clash of Clans, etc, almost certainly hired an IP lawyer to draft user agreements, and do a comprehensive regulatory analysis. Just so you know the type of undertaking this is, if you intend to do it yourself or if you intend to hire out the project: this is not boilerplate work and the regs are not going to be easy for most non-lawyers to wade thru. Secondly, if I were hired to do this project, I would need a minimum of a 5k retainer and a clear understanding that the end product would take a while and cost in excess of that #...maybe by double. FYI